Why do i have to port forwarding? - Podman
I have Next.js project which build using podman, once it's succeed to build an image, i tried to run but i can't access it locally using localhost. I was using: podman run [my_project]
But then i'm using: podman run -p 3000:3000 [my_project] and it worked.
and i'm curious since i'm a newbie, do i have to do port forwarding each time i want to run an image? (only image, because i tried to start the container after port forwarding, it's still works.)
This is my Containerfile:
# Node.js image as the base image, latest version
FROM node:20

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install project dependenies
RUN npm ci

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

#Build the Next.js app
RUN npm run build

# Initialize container port
EXPOSE 3000

#Specify the command to start the Next.js app
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"] 

The reasons why i have to port forwarding so that it could run locally on localhost, since the default of the hostname is 0.0.0.0

Running images are otherwise known as "containers". And yes, without port mapping, there would be no network access from your localhost to the container

@Phil is the usage for podman the same way as docker? thanks for the reference

I believe so. It's meant to be a near drop-in replacement
